# Sonata admin missing css files

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4, sonata

Working on a site with php 7.2, Symfony 4 and Sonata admin 3.

In dev, on my machine, everything works fine, the site itself, and the two admins (user and content).

I have put everything on the final server (unfortunately, file by file, no console with S4 ! so, no "composer:install"...).

Still on dev, the site works fine, all functionalities.

But when I try to use the admin page, I only get a non-formatted page. None of the assets (css and js) seems to work!

However the source code are identical, on localhost and the distant site...

Can anyone help me

**Edit** : I found where the issue comes from : it's linked to .htaccess.

The http address I use ends in /public/index.php. I use .htaccess to shorten it and when using the .htacces redirection I can't get the assets of the admin page, while it works fine without redirection.

Is there something I should change in my .htaccess code ?

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you find any errors or logs that are relevant?

Comment: After I found my explanation, I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246630/symfony2-sonataadmin-assets-not-loading